# Which algorithm does CryptGenRandom use on my laptop?

Tags: cryptography, windows, hardware, random, algorithm

I have an Ideapad Gaming laptop by Lenovo, with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H processor. On this laptop I have Windows 10 installed. To generate random numbers, I use the CryptGenRandom function. However, I found out that this function has been updated through the years. For example, in the past the algorithm used RC4 (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom)), but that algorithm contained a bug. The algorithm has been revised since then, but it has never been published. Does it still use an RC4 algorithm, or has it another name now? Is it the same on my laptop as on all other modern Windows laptops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this API is deprecated, so this is not used on your modern laptop except for if you have legacy software, the manual for the modern API is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-features). It is 100% up to the programs that use the API on what cipher modes or the exact stream they pull out of, so I can't answer what the modern API uses.

To answer the question about the deprecated API, it depends on what version of Windows the API is on.

> In Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later, an implementation of the AES counter-mode based PRNG specified in NIST Special Publication 800-90 is used. In Windows Vista, Windows Storage Server 2003, and Windows XP, the PRNG specified in Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) 186-2 is used.

Comment: ‘so this is not used on your modern laptop except for if you have legacy software’: the Python secrets module and Python random module and os.urandom use this algorithm to generate random numbers. So i think that this API is used a lot by popular modern software.

Comment: I recently found this out, see this question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/107190/is-python-secrets-module-using-a-unsafe-rng-on-windows

Comment: @Riemann My point wasn't to say that modern software couldn't use it per se, but that the Microsoft developers intend for all modern software to go to their new shiny API.

Comment: I searched the NIST special publication and it doesn’t mention RC4. Now the question remains whether the Secure Key Technology is used in my case. I think that this is not explained in the NIST publication, since it only contains recommendations.

Comment: I think I will just ask that in a new question.